# Is it possible to convert money automatically when user selected the specific country using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, converters, currency

I want to convert the whole product price on a page with country specific currency and display them on the page. Is it possible to do this without adding the custom code to price for fetching the value of a product? Can I do this automatically using jquery. If anybody can do this before, please share your experience.

I am using the API to fetching the live currency rates.

Ex: If a site has a base currency $30 USD and user have selected currency INR then the whole product price will be changed to Rs. 1800 INR with total amount.

I did this manually to add the product price in an html element and bind the value in a container so that I can fetch the whole product price.

Is any other way to do this?

Comment: yes it is possible..on change of the country convert the money value based on the country's currency

Comment: Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936150/change-currency-depending-on-country

Comment: Yes! I know and I already do this but if I want to do this with any CMS which does not allow to customize the code. How can I handle that?